# How to use ansible to run a script which ask user input?

Tags: shell, ansible, user-input

I want to run a shell script using ansible but the shell script requires user input to execute successfully,

**For example**: my shell script asking the unique id for an `ossec agent`, through ansible I can able to predefined my `unique id (user input`).

Comment: [expect](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/expect_module.html#expect-executes-a-command-and-responds-to-prompts) module might help.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use EXPECT module:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/expect_module.html

```
- name: Case insensitive unique id string match
  expect:
    command: ./myscript.sh
    responses:
      "Please enter your uniqueid": "myID"
      # Your input in myscript.sh
  no_log: true
```

Requirements

The below requirements are needed on the host that executes this module.

python >= 2.6

pexpect >= 3.3

Comment: it is possible to call a unique id from file? I had a 100 unique id

Comment: U can parse content from your text file to string variable and afterwards run expect&command with "with_items" option, example, if yours ids in file comma separated, then u can add: with_items: {{ myStringVar.split(',') }}, and in responses specify item: "Please enter your uniqueid": "{{ item }}"

Answer (score 0):

This could help you as a starting point:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  vars_prompt:
  - name: your_name
    prompt: "Enter your name"
    private: no

  tasks:
  - name: print name
    assert: that="your_name.strip()"
    args:
      msg: "The your_name argument shouldn't be empty!"

  - debug:
        var: your_name
```

Check more about `prompts`, `vars_prompt` here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html