# Windows Ansible role is hanging/freezing because of dialog

Tags: ansible, winget

I'm probably trying to do something stupid, but I have been writing roles to install applications via WinGet (Windows package manager) and via `ansible.windows.win_command`. I am on WSL2 (Ubuntu) connecting to Windows 10 on the same computer. This is working for the most part, but some roles are returning error which I think I have fixed with `ignore_errors: yes`.

However, I think some are launching error dialogs even when running WinGet in silent mode and as the application installer is waiting on user input, the task never completes. Should I use async and poll or what can I do? I am mostly interested in having as many applications installed via WinGet via Ansible until there is WinGet support. If a role fails I can install via WinGet manually, but I want the playbook with all the roles to run to the end at least.

Comment: It looks like an issue was created to support the Windows Package Manager in Ansible. https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.windows/issues/89

Comment: @Suirtimed Yeah, I know, but thanks! I've been F5:ing that issue for quite sometime now. Maybe soon I'll be forced to continue on the PR without knowing anything about Ansible module or PowerShell development. :D

Answer (score 1):

You may be getting hit by the dialog to accept source agreements or package agreements.

You can either [pass the flags as suggested](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/discussions/1536#discussioncomment-1414887) or you could try the [EXPECT module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56110622/how-to-use-ansible-to-run-a-script-which-ask-user-input).